# func (*TCPConn) Read update the bytes value even though argument is not pointer

Tags: go

My understanding of Golang method/function argument is that it works by `call by value`. But I came across this method call `func (c *TCPConn) Read(b []byte) (int, error)` where the argument is non pointer but it updates the variable value in caller. I think I am missing something. Pls help to understand this case.

Comment: Rea about slices: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/7

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It depends on the type of that argument. `[]byte` is a slice and slices act actually like pointers. Maps are also pointers so consider it when you use slice and Maps in your functions.

https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro:

> A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer
> to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum
> length of the segment).

Comment: You say "slices are actually pointers." No. A slice descriptor is implemented as a value, a struct, which consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity,